# Retrieve and reuse object handle from C function in C#

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I have a dynamic library (server_connect.so) that Im trying to interact with using C#.

*server_connect.so* exposes a few functions to interact with a "server". The user has to initiate/create a connection using *fnConnect* function which returns a server handle. This can then be used to call other functions e.g. send a command
to the server *fnSendCommand*.
All latter functions require a server handle object returned by *fnConnect*

How can I retrieve the server handle and pass it to other methods that call these subsequent functions i.e. fnSendCommand?

So far I have defined a method that calls *fnConnect* function, this seems to execute without any errors but I don't know how to store a reference to that object and then pass it to the next function

```
        [DllImport("server_connect.so", 
            EntryPoint = "fnConnect", 
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
            CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr ConnectFunction();

        [DllImport("server_connect.so",
            EntryPoint = "fnSendCommand",
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
            CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern void SendCommand(object serverHandle, string command);

        public object Connect()
        {
            var serverRef = ConnectFunction();
            return serverRef;
        }

        public CommandSend(object serverHandle, string command)
        {
            SendCommand(serverHandle, command);
        }
```

Comment: IntPtr is not an object, but good enough to store a handle.  Fix the declaration of SendCommand(), make the first parameter an IntPtr as well.  Do beware that CharSet.Auto is not terribly likely to be correct, most C code uses char* for strings.  That's CharSet.Ansi

Comment: Use `IntPtr` as the handle type, not `object`. IntPtr means a pointer-sized integer. As the C library probably uses a pointer as a handle, it’s a matching data type.